# Una tarea con Array - Vector

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer lo siguiente: Se pide por consola que se ingrese vía teclado, el nombre del usuario, su dni y su año de nacimiento. Se debe construir una patente, del estilo de argentina AB 123 CD. Donde las letras A y B deben ser las dos primeras vocales del nombre que se ingresó. Los números 123 deben ser los últimos 3 números del dni. Y las letras C y D deben estar dadas por los últimos dos números del año de nacimiento, donde por ejemplo si el numero es 0 la letra es A, si el numero es 1 la letra es B, y así hasta el numero 9 donde la letra es J.

Mi problema es que: al querer imprimir las letras A y B con printf (lo hice en el ultimo de todo) , no me imprime nada.

Quisiera saber porque sucede ese problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char nombre[30];
int i=0;
int j=0;
int dni[8];
int nacimiento[4];

printf("INTRODUZCA SU NOMBRE: " );
scanf("%s",nombre);

printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

printf("PORFAVOR INGRESES SU DNI (DIGITO A DIGITO)\n\n");

for(i=1;i<=8;i++){
printf("INTRODUZCA EL %d%c DIGITO DE SU DNI: ",i,248);
scanf("%d",&dni[i]);
}
printf("\n");

printf("SU DNI ES: ");
for(i=1;i<=8;i++){
printf("%d",dni[i]);
}

printf("\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

printf("PORFAVOR INGRESES SU A%cO DE NACIMIENTO (DIGITO A DIGITO)\n\n",165);
for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
{
    printf("INGRESE EL %d%c DIGITO DE SU NACIMIENTO: ",j,248);
    scanf("%d",&nacimiento[j]);
}
printf("\n");

printf("SU A%cO DE NACIMIENTO ES: ",165);
for(j=1;j<=4;j++){
    printf("%d",nacimiento[j]);
}


printf("\n\n------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

printf("%c%c",nombre[0],nombre[1]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por que en esa muestra le faltaba poner los while o for y los swicht o if
lo pudiste resolver??

Answer (score 2):

Al guardar el dni en `int dni[8]` empezabas el for desde 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char nombre[30];
int i=0;
int j=0;
int dni[8];
int nacimiento[4];

printf("INTRODUZCA SU NOMBRE: " );
scanf("%s",nombre);

printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

printf("PORFAVOR INGRESES SU DNI (DIGITO A DIGITO)\n\n");

for(i=0;i<=7;i++){
printf("INTRODUZCA EL %d%c DIGITO DE SU DNI: ",i+1,248);
scanf("%d",&dni[i]);
}
printf("\n");

printf("SU DNI ES: ");
for(i=0;i<=7;i++){
printf("%d",dni[i]);
}

printf("\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

printf("PORFAVOR INGRESES SU A%cO DE NACIMIENTO (DIGITO A DIGITO)\n\n",165);
for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
{
    printf("INGRESE EL %d%c DIGITO DE SU NACIMIENTO: ",j,248);
    scanf("%d",&nacimiento[j]);
}
printf("\n");

printf("SU A%cO DE NACIMIENTO ES: ",165);
for(j=1;j<=4;j++){
    printf("%d",nacimiento[j]);
}


printf("\n\n------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

printf("%c%c",nombre[0],nombre[1]);

return 0;
}
```

Ahora en principio hace lo que pides.

Comment: De verdad? yo estoy probando y no me imprime nada, lo del: 
printf("%c%c",nombre[0],nombre[1]);